# JFreeChart setDataset for XYPlot

Tags: java, jfreechart

in my diploma i have some time expensive calculation in `SwingWorker` class. When `SwingWorker` call `done` method. All result should put on chart. About result - I do not know how many values in legend will be. I did it all but chart not refreshed. Not show series at all. I try through `dataset.addSeries(someSeries)` and `chart.getXYPlot().setDataset(someDataset)`. In examples project like DynamicDataDemo1.java and etc. they just add new point to series and not refresh/repaint graphics. Why graphics not refreshed? I have information what `add` method of `XYSeries` send `SeriesChangeEvent` to all registered listeners and automatically refresh chart. But i don't know how many `XYSeries` will be. Can not understand how i can refresh chart through `setDataset` method of XYPlot.

```
public class OutputChart extends JPanel {

private JFreeChart chart;
private XYSeriesCollection dataset;
private ChartPanel chartPanel;

public OutputChart() {
    dataset = createDataset();  
    chart = createChart(dataset);   
    chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);   
    chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(800, 400));   
    add(chartPanel);
}

/**  
 * Creates a chart.  
 *   
 * @param dataset  the data for the chart.  
 *   
 * @return a chart.  
 */   
private static JFreeChart createChart(XYDataset dataset) {   

    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(   
        "Результаты вычислений алгоритма",// chart title   
        "N",                      // x axis label   
        "V",                      // y axis label   
        dataset,                  // data   
        PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,   
        true,                     // include legend   
        true,                     // tooltips   
        false                     // urls   
    );   

    chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);   

    XYPlot plot = chart.getXYPlot();   
    plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.lightGray);   
    plot.setAxisOffset(new RectangleInsets(5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0));   
    plot.setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.white);   
    plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.white);   

    plot.setDomainCrosshairVisible(true);   
    plot.setRangeCrosshairVisible(true);   

    XYLineAndShapeRenderer renderer    
        = (XYLineAndShapeRenderer) plot.getRenderer();   
    renderer.setShapesVisible(true);   
    renderer.setShapesFilled(true);   

    // change the auto tick unit selection to integer units only...   
    NumberAxis rangeAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();   
    rangeAxis.setStandardTickUnits(NumberAxis.createIntegerTickUnits());   

    return chart;   

}

/**
 * Create  data set for chart
 * @return empty data set
 */
private XYSeriesCollection createDataset(){
    return new XYSeriesCollection();
}

    public void setDataset(XYSeries series){ //try through addSeries and setDataset of XYPlot.
         dataset.addSeries(series);
    }

    public void setDataset(XYDataset dataset){ //try through addSeries and setDataset of XYPlot.
         chart.getXYPlot().setDataset(dataset);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [example](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/jfreechartdemo) shows adding (or removing) a series to (or from) a [`DefaultXYDataset`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/xy/DefaultXYDataset.html); no special effort is required.

An instance of [`XYSeriesCollection`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/xy/XYSeriesCollection.html), a related `XYDataset`, should work similarly, as long as the application correctly uses the [event dispatch thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html). As suggested in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4637725/230513) and the [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) API, either `process()` or `done()` should meet that obligation.

By default, `XYPlot` registers itself as a `DatasetChangeListener`. Verify that this has not been disabled.

An [sscce](http://sscce.org/) may shed some light on the problem.

Comment: Sorry i just now find my mistake. I renew data in wrong instance of chart object. I very disappointed in my hand. But thanks for your suggestion. I also check your suggestions before.